# Javascript how do I use a while loop on this animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, widget, jquery-animate

I've been working with javascript for a few days now but I'm currently stuck on while looping/using switches this animation.

essentially the program will "level up" into a new colored image after moving 3 times, and start from the beginning. I have a gold level up so far, but I want to keep changing colors for the next level ups. I'm trying to add a new classlist to the animated image, a different one for every counter, but nothing seems to be working. this is how I have it:

```
$("#go").click(function() {
  var dest = parseInt($("#block").css("margin-left").replace("px", "")) + 100;
  
  if (dest < 400) {
    $("#block").animate({
      marginLeft: dest + "px"
    }, 700);
  } else {
      
    $("#block").animate({
      marginLeft:  "10px"
    }, 100);
    //if counter = 1
    document.getElementById('block').classList.add("gold")
    //if counter = 2
    //document.getElementById('block').classList.remove("gold")
    //document.getElementById('block').classList.add("pink")
       //... etc
    
    //counter += 1 
  }
});
```

and here is the link to run the program (click the run text)
http://jsfiddle.net/mept9g1u/

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise your `counter` variable to 0 **outside** of the click event listener, otherwise it's reset to 0 every time you click.

```js
var counter = 0 // ⭐️ Declare counter here

$("#go").click(function() {
  var dest = parseInt($("#block").css("margin-left").replace("px", "")) + 100;

  if (dest < 400) {
    $("#block").animate({ marginLeft: dest + "px" }, 700);
  } else {
    $("#block").animate({ marginLeft:  "10px" }, 100);

    counter++;

    if (counter === 1) {
        document.getElementById('block').classList.add("gold")
    }
    if (counter === 2) {
      document.getElementById('block').classList.remove("gold")
      document.getElementById('block').classList.add("pink")
    }
    // etc.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    function BoxAnimate(){
    var count= 0;
        while( count < 6){
            $(".boxanimate").eq(count).stop(true, true).delay(1000*count).animate({
                left:"400px"
            });
            count++;
        }
    }

    BoxAnimate();
});
```

```css
.boxanimate { background:Green; 
        margin-bottom:10px;
        margin-left:30px;
        height:150px; 
        width:150px;
        font-family:Arial;
        font-size:30px;
        text-align:center;
        color:#fff;
        line-height:150px;
        position:relative;
        clear:both;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ani-wrp">
        <div class="boxanimate"> data1 </div>
        <div class="boxanimate"> data2 </div>
        <div class="boxanimate"> data3 </div>
        <div class="boxanimate"> data4 </div>
        <div class="boxanimate"> data5 </div>
        
</div>
```